# Nokogiriのエラーについて

Tags: nokogiri

DBの作成と最新状態へ移行すために、
下記のコマンドを、実行しました。

```
bundle exec rake db:create
bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundle exec rake db:seed
bundle exec rails g spree:install
bundle exec rake spree_sample:load
```

その結果、

```
Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.9.7, but has dynamically loaded 2.9.4
```

というエラーが出てきます。
修正方法がわかりません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.9.7, but has dynamically loaded 2.9.4

を訳すと

起動した Nokogiri　は バージョン 2.9.7 の LibXMLライブラリを使うように作られていますが、バージョン 2.9.4のLibXMLが読み込まれました。（「違うLibXMLだと正しく動くかどうかわかんないから、Nokogiriの起動をあきらめざるを得ませんでした」という意味）

という感じです。

バージョン 2.9.7 の LibXML をインストールして、LibXMLといえばバージョン 2.9.7 の LibXMLが読み込まれるようにすれば、解決すると思われます。

まずは、システムに組み込まれているLibXMLのバージョンを確認しましょう。

Answer (score -1):

"Nokogiri was built against LibXM version"で検索してみてください。